# As soon as python class receives QMessageBox.Information as argument, resizing by stylesheet won't work

Tags: python, pyqt5, qmessagebox

In python, I created a class “ScrollMessageBoxShowRC“ , which receives three arguments (see below):

```
result = ScrollMessageBoxShowRC(QMessageBox.Information, '', '')

result.exec_()
```

Originally, I instantiated the class with solely "None" as argument. As long as it received only "None", I could resize the class as follows: self.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea{min-width:410 px; min-height: 600px}"), see below:

```
class ScrollMessageBoxShowRC(QMessageBox):  

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       QMessageBox.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
       
       self.setWindowTitle("Contacts to view or to delete.")
       
       scroll = QScrollArea(self)
       scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
       self.content = QWidget()
       scroll.setWidget(self.content)
       lay = QVBoxLayout(self.content)
       lay.setStyleSheet("min-width: 100px;");

       dlts = {} 
       self.x = {}
       
       for rc in dbaccess.allRC():
          dlt = QCheckBox('delete', self)
          dlt.stateChanged.connect(partial(self.btnstateDel, dlt, dlts))
          dlt.setObjectName(rc[9])
 
          qb = QPushButton(rc[9], self)
          qb.released.connect(partial(self.button_releasedRC, rc[9]))
          lay.addWidget(qb)
          lay.addWidget(dlt)
 
       self.buttonClicked.connect(self.msgButtonClickDel)   
       self.layout().addWidget(scroll, 0, 0, 1, self.layout().columnCount())
       self.setStyleSheet("QScrollArea{min-width:410 px; min-height: 600px}")

   def btnstateDel(self, dlt, dlts):
       
       dlts[dlt.objectName()] = False
       
       if dlt.isChecked:
           dlts[dlt.objectName()] = True
        
       self.x = dlts

   def msgButtonClickDel(self, i):
       if i.text() == "OK":
           dbaccess.deleteRCs(self.x)

   def button_releasedRC(self, nameshow):

       pass
```

Since I changed the arguments to QMessageBox.Information, '', '' the stylesheet setting the size of the Widget seems no longer to have been in vigour. I could not find out why this is the case. Could anybody give me a hint what I might have overlooked?

Comment: It seems that you're actually using none of the QMessageBox features (except for the icon), why don't you use a QDialog instead? Also: 1. layouts are not widget, they have no `setStyleSheet`; 2. why are you using the `released` signal?.

Answer (score 0):

QMessageBox is a special type of QDialog that creates its own layout on execution. When created without arguments, it behaves almost like a basic QDialog, but as soon as elements are added (most importantly, the icon), the internal layout takes precedence and in certain cases is also completely deleted a recreated.

Since QMessageBox is generally intended as a *convenience* simple class, and it seems that the only *actual* specific feature used here is the icon, there's no need to use it at all.

A basic QDialog can be used instead, and the icon can be loaded using the style, just like QMessageBox does. Then you can add buttons using [QDialogButtonBox](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html).

```
class ScrollMessageBoxShowRC(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QDialog.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)

        icon = self.style().standardIcon(
            QStyle.SP_MessageBoxInformation, None, self)
        iconSize = self.style().pixelMetric(
            QStyle.PM_MessageBoxIconSize, None, self)
        self.iconLabel = QLabel(pixmap=icon.pixmap(iconSize, iconSize))

        layout.addWidget(self.iconLabel, 0, 0, 
            alignment=Qt.AlignLeft|Qt.AlignTop)

        self.scroll = QScrollArea()
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll, 0, 1)
        # ...

        self.buttonBox = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonBox, 
            layout.rowCount(), 0, 1, layout.columnCount())
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def accept(self):
        dbaccess.deleteRCs(self.x)
        super().accept()
```

The icons of QMessageBox are listed in the [`StandardPixmap` enum](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#StandardPixmap-enum) of QStyle.

Further important notes:

- you should not use string matching for buttons, especially if the names are set by the library: "OK" can be a different string in other systems (for instance, on my computer the "k" is lowercase);
- even if you're using the local `dlts` in partial, you're actually always updating `self.x`, which makes it pointless to have two dictionaries and also sending them to the connected function;
- the `released` signal is emitted whenever a button is released, which can also happen when the user presses the mouse on the button and moves the mouse *outside* it while keeping the mouse pressed; use `clicked` instead;
- `isChecked` is a function, you should use `if dlt.isChecked():`, or, better `dlts[dlt.objectName()] = dlt.isChecked()`, instead of setting it to `False` every time before actually checking;
- `stateChanged` is used for *three state* check boxes that can be partially checked; if you only need a bool value, use `toggled`;
- for basic signals that are *directly* (not queued, like in threads) connected to functions for which the behavior is known and specific for those signal senders, you can use [`self.sender()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) instead of partials; in this way, you can also directly use the signal arguments instead of querying the property; if you're not interested in the argument, ignore it in the function signature; always use `sender()` with care, though;

```
        # ...
        self.dlts = {} 
       
        for rc in dbaccess.allRC():
            dlt = QCheckBox('delete', self)
            dlt.toggled.connect(self.btnstateDel)
            dlt.setObjectName(rc[9])

            qb = QPushButton(rc[9], self)
            qb.clicked.connect(self.button_releasedRC)
            lay.addWidget(qb)
            lay.addWidget(dlt)

    def btnstateDel(self, checked):
        self.dlts[self.sender().objectName()] = checked

    def button_releasedRC(self):
        nameshow = self.sender()
        # ...
```